# Android NDK - Include a c++ header in a different header?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, javah

I have an `Ability.h` file that is dependent on an `Effect.h` file.

I need to use **javah** to generate my header, but I'm **unable to define an Effect dependency** in my `Ability.java` class from which I'd like the c++ header to be generated.

Example:

```
public class Ability {

  static {
    System.loadLibrary("com_test_Effect");
    System.loadLibrary("com_test_Ability");
  }

  public native Effect foo(Effect x);

}
```

This code generates an *.h file **without** the `foo()` function, as if it couldn't recognize it. It does generate a proper file if I swap the return type to int and don't include the com_test_Effect.

I do have both of the modules defined in the Android.mk file (com_test_Effect and com_test_Ability).

How to include an another c++ file directly in the `Xyz.java` class from which the `*.h` is generated by **javah** ?

Edit: The question can also be asked like this: Is there a way to pass C++-type arguments or return a C++-type value from a function that is an interface between C++ and Java ? (The interfacing medium being JNI.) For example, you can do so with basic types like int which then gets converted to jint and so on.

Comment: "don't include the com_test_Effect". That part of it has no effect. You aren't 'including' anything here, you are loading libraries at runtime. It has no magical effect on the Java compiler or `javah`. I would ask have you compiled the `Effect` class?

Comment: @EJP Yes, the Effect is compiled, but just because it doesn't depend on anything. I wonder how to use c++ types in Xyz.java so that javah can then generate a proper *.h file.

Comment: @EJP Suppose i don't want to use "Effect" there but std::string. Given that stl is enabled, i still can't include the header. Well, i can do it in the *.cpp file but not in the c++ header.

Comment: You can return or pass to JNI function only the Java types (jint, jstring, jobject, ... etc). Not a C types (pointers/structs), and not a C++ types (std::strings). Can you show us your header files?

Answer (score -1):

What about returning an Object:

```
private native Object fooNative(Object x);
```

Then convert it so that it has the same signature:

```
public Effect foo(Effect x) {
    return (Effect)fooNative(x);
}
```